# How to read content of a JSON file in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, getjson

I am trying to get information from an API. Basically I have a URL that returns a JSON data, and I will just need to use it.

```js
var url = "http://212.18.63.135:9034/played?sid=1&type=json";
$.getJSON(url, function(data) {
    console.log(data)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

The above is my code, and it does not work.
This is an API that provides live data, so I am not sure if I can use ajax instead...

Any idea how to make it work?

**UPDATE:**

I updated the URL, and now it gives `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` error. I had a look at other question related to CORS and they all suggest to make configuration in the server side as much as I understood. But I am not looking into fixing the CORS error, I am just looking for a solution to access these JSON data.

So I hope it does not get duplicated as my point is different in this question.

Comment: Well, the url doesn't work ... fix that and you are all good

Comment: Two things comes in mind when seeing this code. Do you load jQuery first before running your own javascript code? And Wrap the inside a jquery ready function ```$(function() {
  // Handler for .ready() called.
});```

Comment: `$.getJSON` is just shorthand for `$.ajax`, and you should use `.fail` to check for errors.

Comment: @LGSon Thanks for you comment. I updated the URL. Could you check the post again? Thanks

Comment: @jcaron Thanks for your comment. Just updated the question.

Comment: You can use chrome extension https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this way.

Adding `callback=?` to your URL turned your request to JSONP, so no CORS

More [information](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) about getJSON and JSONP.

If you interested how JSONP works you can read that [article](http://bob.ippoli.to/archives/2005/12/05/remote-json-jsonp/)

```js
var url = "http://212.18.63.135:9034/played?sid=1&type=json&callback=?";
$.getJSON(url, function(data) {
    console.log(data)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to access the data without doing any changes in the server.Try this  chrome extension [Allow-Control-Allow-Origin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi/related?hl=en).

I just tested with the above, it's working fine.(browser specific though)

But this is not the recommended solution, you should set the configuration on server side.